# Why does my GeoServer Tile Caching not work？

Tags: geoserver

after I upload some tiff, I'd like to slice layer, but the Web page always error.

I hope the web page doesn't error. Can anyone give me some advice to successfully slice layer.
Thanks to everyone who give me advice~, have a nice day!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.